# Interpretation of Powers of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

Suppose there is a square binary matrix (Adjacency matrix of a graph), $A$.

I got that, the matrices, $A^2$ and $A^3$ are distinct but the set of eigenvalues are same for $A^2$ and $A^3$. It is to be noted that the set of eigenvalues of $A$ is different from the same of $A^2$ and $A^3$. Other powers of $A$ are same as $A^3$.

What does the above result interpret?

Please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any square matrix $A$, the eigenvalues of $A^k$ (counted by algebraic multiplicity) are the $k$'th powers of the eigenvalues of $A$.  I'm having trouble thinking of a case where the eigenvalues of $A^3$ and $A^2$ are the same but are not the same as the eigenvalues of $A$.  Certainly all eigenvalues would be either $0$ or have absolute valu e $1$.  Moreover, if $A$ has rational entries and you have an irrational eigenvalue, it will be algebraic and its conjugates will also be eigenvalues.

Comment: Yes. It is happening. It is a square matrix of size 256. If you want, I can share the matrix to your email and then you can check it.

Comment: OK, please do that.

Comment: Sent to your email. Please check and do the needful.

Comment: OK, I received it.  The characteristic polynomial is $t^{216} (t-1)^{40}$.  The eigenvalues are thus $0$ (with algebraic multiplicity $216$) and $1$ (with algebraic multiplicity $40$).  The same, of course, for all powers of $A$.  The minimal polynomial of $A$ is $t^3 (t-1)$. Thus there are some "defective" eigenvalues...

Comment: Professor, can you make it clear the notion "defective"? Also What does mean that the higher powers of A are same with $A^3$?

Comment: Specifically, the Jordan canonical form of $A$ has, it seems, four blocks of size $3$ and 36 blocks of size $2$, all for eigenvalue $0$; the blocks for eigenvalue $1$ all have size $1$.  Thus for a block $B = \pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 1\cr 0 & 0 & 0\cr}$ of size $3$ we have $B^2 = \pmatrix{0 & 0 & 1\cr 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0\cr}$ and $B^k = 0$ for all $k \ge 3$.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $\lambda^{n}$ is an eigenvalue of $A^{n}$. The eigenvectors are invariant for powers of a matrix.

We note that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $A^{2}v = A(\lambda * v) = \lambda * (Av) = \lambda * (\lambda * v) = \lambda^{2} v$. We simply apply the identity that $Av = \lambda * v$. Of course, I am assuming $v$ to be the corresponding eigenvector.